# Is there a way to display two projects in the same window in Intellij?

Tags: java, eclipse, intellij-idea

In Eclipse, you can import two projects and they can be displayed in parallel in one view. In Intellij, is this possible? It seems that two projects cann't be displayed together. is that true?

Comment: I doubt that this is possible at all, especially if the two projects are completely disjoint.

Comment: Use modules, see https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/eclipse.html for details.

Comment: Yes, two projects are not related in any way.  Does modules still work?

Comment: You can open the second project and choose: "Open in new window". As far as I know IntelliJ has no panel for multiple projects navigation.

Comment: Why is my "open recent" disabled? I can't switch to another project, which is also open.

Comment: Maybe because of this (?) :
https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/207089089-SOLVED-Where-do-I-set-the-maximum-number-of-recent-projects-to-be-shown-in-the-File-Open-Recent-list-

Comment: It's a matter of choice of course, but my favorite IDE is Eclipse, as well; not only for thease reasons, but also because of reacher GiT-management tools, Maven repository manipulation, and pom.xml editing, and it's free too.

Comment: Eclipse has other important advantages as well: FindBugs, Databse connection profiles for data manipulations, etc. I think it's just much easier to work with.

Comment: What do you mean by "Maven repository manipulation, and pom.xml editing". Intellij has similar functionalities. You can edit pom.xml easily in Intellij too.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149298/discussion-between-user697911-and-lowlevel).

Comment: Ok. But I don't know how to do it.